# homotopy equivalence between configuration spaces on non-homeomorphic spaces

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, homotopy-theory, configuration-spaces

(1). Let $D^m$ be the closed $m$-disc in $\mathbb{R}^m$. For each $k$, does the $k$-th configuration space on $D^m$ homotopy equivalent to the $k$-th configuration space on $\mathbb{R}^m$
$$
F(D^m,k)\simeq F(\mathbb{R}^m,k)
$$
or not?

(2). Let $M$ be a manifold. For each $k$, does the $k$-th configuration space on $M\times [0,1]$ homotopy equivalent to the $k$-th configuration space on $M\times (0,1)$
$$
F(M\times [0,1],k)\simeq F(M\times(0,1),k)
$$
or not?

How to prove these two? Thanks.

Comment: The general statement is that the configuration space of $k$ points on a manifold $M$ with boundary is homotopy equivalent to the configuration space of $k$ points on $\text{int}(M)$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: Thanks so much. Could you give any references/proofs for the general statement?

Comment: See Definition $2.3$, Proposition $2.4$, and Example $2.5$ of [these notes](https://scholar.harvard.edu/files/rastern/files/252xnotes.pdf).